# Chrome In-Brower SCSS Editing with Stylesheet Versions

Tags: google-chrome, sass

I use workspaces and sourcemapping to live-edit my SCSS files in Chrome with live reload functionality.

However the live-reload part breaks if I add a version to the stylesheet that is being generated by the SCSS. The stylesheet is still saved and changed in the background, but Chrome does not inject the changes.

eg. `<link rel="stylesheet href="style.css?v=255"/>`

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a current limitation on Chromes part and does also apply to plain CSS files. As a simple workaround you can execute this bookmarklet before attempting to change your source file:

```
javascript:(function(){var s=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(var i=0;i<s.length;++i){var q=s[i].href.indexOf('?');if(q!==-1)s[i].href=s[i].href.substr(0,q)}})()
```

(What it does is look for `<link>` tags with an `href` containing a query string, and removes the latter if found).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the workaround, but I change the SCSS so often that it would make more sense for me to just remove the query string once and add it back before pushing live.

Comment: @Chrome Team - please fix this!

Comment: Well if you're using some sort of task runner, which I assume, you could use it to inject a script that does it for you during debug builds :)

Comment: For other people with this issue, you can also check within your code if your'e on a local server, and conditionally include this JS within the page. It works like a charm!